# What is this protection that seems to prevent ROP when ASLR in ON?

Tags: disassembly, rop

I was doing some tests to train myself to ROP when `ASLR` is `ON` and `NX` is enabled.

I created this small program for testing purpose

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char buff[128];

    gets(buff);

    char *password = "I am h4cknd0";

    if (strcmp(buff, password)) {
        printf("You password is incorrect\n");
    } else {
        printf("Access GRANTED !\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I compiled it on a 64bits Ubuntu with this command

```
gcc -o rop rop.c -m32 -fno-stack-protector  -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now,-z,noexecstack -static
```

When I open the beast in `gdb` and disassemble the main function, I get the following

```
0x0804887c <+0>:       lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
0x08048880 <+4>:       and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x08048883 <+7>:       push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
0x08048886 <+10>:      push   ebp
0x08048887 <+11>:      mov    ebp,esp
0x08048889 <+13>:      push   ecx
0x0804888a <+14>:      sub    esp,0x94
0x08048890 <+20>:      sub    esp,0xc
0x08048893 <+23>:      lea    eax,[ebp-0x8c]
0x08048899 <+29>:      push   eax
0x0804889a <+30>:      call   0x804f100 <gets>
0x0804889f <+35>:      add    esp,0x10
0x080488a2 <+38>:      mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x80bb388
0x080488a9 <+45>:      sub    esp,0x8
0x080488ac <+48>:      push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
0x080488af <+51>:      lea    eax,[ebp-0x8c]
0x080488b5 <+57>:      push   eax
0x080488b6 <+58>:      call   0x8048280
0x080488bb <+63>:      add    esp,0x10
0x080488be <+66>:      test   eax,eax
0x080488c0 <+68>:      je     0x80488d4 <main+88>
0x080488c2 <+70>:      sub    esp,0xc
0x080488c5 <+73>:      push   0x80bb395
0x080488ca <+78>:      call   0x804f280 <puts>
0x080488cf <+83>:      add    esp,0x10
0x080488d2 <+86>:      jmp    0x80488e4 <main+104>
0x080488d4 <+88>:      sub    esp,0xc
0x080488d7 <+91>:      push   0x80bb3af
0x080488dc <+96>:      call   0x804f280 <puts>
0x080488e1 <+101>:     add    esp,0x10
0x080488e4 <+104>:     mov    eax,0x0
0x080488e9 <+109>:     mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
0x080488ec <+112>:     leave  
0x080488ed <+113>:     lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
0x080488f0 <+116>:     ret
```

It's the first time I have these function prologue and epilogue

**Prologue**

```
0x0804887c <+0>:       lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
0x08048880 <+4>:       and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x08048883 <+7>:       push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
```

**Epilogue**

```
0x080488e9 <+109>:     mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
0x080488ec <+112>:     leave  
0x080488ed <+113>:     lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
0x080488f0 <+116>:     ret
```

Because of these, I need to know `ESP` value when the `main` function is called when exploiting the vulnerable binary with ROP, but since `ASLR` is enabled, it's not possible.

**PS** : I assure you this is a program I wrote myself for training purpose, it's not part of any challenge or CTF.

Thanks for your time and knowledge :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a protection but juste a prologue / epilogue that your compiler will produce.
You can check the produced assembly with different versions of gcc right there: https://gcc.godbolt.org/

And in your context, you can control ECX. But what if you just control the last byte only ? Then you might fall on some of your input in the stack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's totally right. I tried to use another compiler and did the following command `clang -o rop rop.c -m32 -fno-stack-protector  -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now,-z,noexecstack -static` and now I have a perfect well know prologue/epilogue :)

Answer (score 1):

While not a part of the official 386 SysV ABI, there is a de-facto requirement that the stack pointer is aligned to 16 bytes at all times when calling system functions (enforced by the de-facto standard compiler (GCC) since several years ago:[1](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38496),[2](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27537)). That's why the prolog of the `main` function contains the `and esp,0xfffffff0` instruction. Only the `main()` function needs to do that, other functions usually don't perform stack realignment since they assume they're already called with 16-byte alignment (unless you use `-mrealignstack`).

So instead of using another compiler you could try putting the vulnerable code in a separate function, not `main` directly.

Comment: Thanks for this useful information. I already published my article but I'll think about putting the vulnerable code in a separate function.